# Proper way to inject a dependency into DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to create a project using a DDD and microservice approach and I have a small question about sending domain events to another service. I use EF Core for database communication and MassTransit to send events.

Right now I have an overridden SaveChangesAsync method in my DBConetxt where I send a domain event trough the bus that I created in Startup.cs using MassTransit.

DBContext:

```
private readonly IBus _bus;

public StudentsDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IBus bus) : base(options)
{
    _bus = bus;
}

...

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    var aggregates = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAggregateRoot>().ToList();

    foreach (var aggregate in aggregates)
    {
        foreach (var domainEvent in aggregate.Entity.DomainEvents)
        {
            await _bus.Publish(domainEvent, domainEvent.GetType(), cancellationToken);
        }
        aggregate.Entity.ClearEvents();
    }

    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

As you can see I need to inject `IBus` into DbContext constructor, and because of it I have some troubles. For example, I can't register my DbContext in Startup.cs file using `AddDbContext` method, because of my constructor, so I need to do it like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IBus>(bus);

services.AddTransient<StudentsDbContext>(provider =>
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"))
        .Options;

    return new StudentsDbContext(options, provider.GetService<IBus>());
});
```

Because of it, I have problems with migrations.

```
Unable to create an object of type 'StudentsDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

And also I want to use pooled DbContext like with `AddDbContextPool`.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How to inject dependency in DbContext properly? It is a good or bad practice?
2. Is it a good approach at all to send domain events from DbContext? Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Not related to the DI issues, but generally you cannot use Pooled DbContext if your context has private fields. You may need to look into that before you attempt to make the switch

Comment: If you want to adhere to DDD principles, I think your entities should't have `DomainEvents` and the context should't have anything to do with a service bus. That's all but Single Responsibility.

Comment: You should separate saving events from sending them. Events should be saved first and published afterwards. What happens if save to database fails? You have published events that don’t exist.

Comment: When events are saved first you should have column in db that tells you whether event has been published. In the event of service failure or similar you can query unpublished events and publish them.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the wrong way.I think you have to correct your code into :

```
public StudentsDbContext(DbContextOptions<OrderingContext> options, IBus bus) : base(options)
        {
            _bus = bus ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bus));

        }
```

and in your startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<StudentsDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString"]);
            });
```